# Spine location mid (2 pages at a time) on Scroll Style UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with Scroll transition style . I want to show 2 pages at a time on an iPad in landscape orientation side by side. But it's unable to set a spine location to mid, while using Scroll Style PVC. Is there some workaround or 3rd party libraries for that?

The app shows a school diary (2 UITableViewControllers side by side with 3 sections which are days in each).

[image: this is the result I wanna get, but with PVC's transition style set to Scroll]